# How to make the coefficients of symbolic polynomials to be decimals and not fractions

Tags: matlab

I want to display a symbolic polynomial with their coefficients as decimals. The coefficients were calculated separately and used to `poly2sym` function to convert it into a symbolic polynomial. The original coefficient vector displays the coefficients as decimals. But when I convert the vector into a symbolic polynomial it turns the coefficients into vector. [image]

Is there a way to make the coefficients decimals and not fractions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried putting another `double()` around your `poly2sym` function?

or You can say something like `output = double(Dz_AA_lossy)` ?

Hmmm, in that case, you can try the matlab VPA:

```
R = vpa(A,d)
```

`R = vpa(A)` uses variable-precision arithmetic (VPA) to compute each element of `A` to at least `d` decimal digits of accuracy, where d is the current setting of digits.

A can be a symbolic or string.

Comment: That doesn't work because Dz_AA_lossy is not a numerical value but a symbolic value. So it returns an error

Comment: try R=vpa(A,d) look for it in matlab help